# Java Selenium: Get get multiple WebElements of the same class

Tags: java, html, selenium, button

This is the Button I want to press:

```
<button class="ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet" data-modal="ProfileTweet-retweet" type="button">
```

The same kind of Button exists multiple time on the site.

I tried pressing it by doing this:

```
By byaXpath = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet')]");

WebElement Element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byaXpath));

Element.click();
```

But after 10 secons I just get this error:

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element

Im kinda lost now. I tried diffrent solution to similar cases but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put button instead of div at the start of your xpath.

```
"//button[contains(@class,'ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet')]"
```

Comment: This will always press the first button of this kind on the site. How do I press another one?

Comment: append[1] for the first button, [2] for the second and so on to the end of the xpath. "//button[contains(@class,'ProfileTweet-actionButton  js-actionButton js-actionRetweet')][2]". You can fetch all the buttons in a list using findElements()